# User defined functions used in competitive programming to take input

Tags: c++

I'm new to competitive programming and I've seen people not using conventional I/O stream such cin or scanf() rather they define their own function to take inputs. There is one such function that I've come across many times and I do not get the code. Here it is

```
int get(){
    char ch;
    while(ch=getchar(),(ch<'0'||ch>'9')&&ch!='-');
    if (ch=='-'){
        int s=0;
        while(ch=getchar(),ch>='0'&&ch<='9')s=s*10+ch-'0';
        return -s;
    }
    int s=ch-'0';
    while(ch=getchar(),ch>='0'&&ch<='9')s=s*10+ch-'0';
    return s;
}
```

what does this getchar() function really does and what is the whole point of this entire function. I guess this must be to optimize the code for taking large inputs but how is it done.
this must be a silly question for the experienced people but since I'm a newbie any help would be appreciated.

Comment: C++ formatted input is very slow compared to many alternatives (such as `getchar()`). In competitions where performance is a factor, this can be a relatively easy way to dramatically increase performance.

Comment: "to optimize the code for taking large inputs" Writing unreadable code is not the way though. Just use the `std::cin` (or `std::scanf` if you want). If you profile and the I/O is the bottleneck, *then* you can start to write a hand-rolled input function, but I doubt that it is faster.

Comment: @Rakete1111  I usually use std::cin but I want to understand this piece of code.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be optimized for large input, but for inputting single integers without any error checking. The very fact that you don't understand what it does is an indication that it is **not** very good code. In good code it is *obvious* what happens. :-)

Comment: @BoPersson What compells people to not simply use std::cin or scanf(). Is there any valid reason.

Comment: @Sohit - If you find some random code on the internet that might not be the best way to do things. People who know how to do this properly might think it's not a big deal, and not care to blog about it.

Comment: Sorry but `getchar()` uses buffered I/O from stdio package.... I'm afraid this is indeed conventional I/O.  If you want to bypass all library functions, use plain system calls (like `read(2)`, for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(ch=getchar(),(ch<'0'||ch>'9')&&ch!='-');
```

skips all input until 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 or - is read

```
if (ch=='-'){
```

If a negative sign is read, continue reading digits:

```
    int s=0;
```

Start with a sum of zero

```
    while(ch=getchar(),ch>='0'&&ch<='9')s=s*10+ch-'0';
```

While reading digits, keep accumulating the sum by moving the previous 1 decimal to the left (multiply by 10) and adding the next digit (subtracting ascii value of `0` leaves `'0'` -> 0, `'1'` -> 1 etc).

```
    return -s;
```

Returns the sum, but negative.

If the negation sign wasn't there, we do EXACTLY the same, but return positive.

### NOTES

There is no parsing delimiters, embedded space, positive signs (+123), neither is there any range/overflow checking. Notable quirk: "aaaaa -" will be parsed as `0`

### Conclusion:

Do not do this. Use scanf or `int i; if (std::cin >> i) { /*something*/ }`

Comment: Thank you for answering my query. I do not get why people are using these kind of functions in competitive programming where we need to do things fast why to complicate things. Is there any valid reason for use of such functions.

Comment: It's probably people coming from C/Assembly background. Really, don't have another explanation. Perhaps they just live by copy/paste